# What if I never respond to an await using a TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm using a `TaskCompletionSource` to create a kind of asynchronous user interface transaction.

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IAutoQuestionAnswer>();

a_question.AnswerSelected += (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(e.Item);

_navigationService.Navigate(ViewNames.AutoQuestionView, a_question);

return tcs.Task;
```

If `AnswerSelected` is never raised and `TrySetResult` is never called on the TCS, will this cause a problem? I have a home button on the `AutoQuestionView` UI that doesn't answer the question at all but takes the user back to the start of the application. In this case, `TrySetResult` will never be called. I've already checked whether threads build up and they don't. I am completely fine if the code following this is simply never called but I want to be sure it won't be something that bites me later on.

Comment: Then anyone waiting for the task will never resume.  That can cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You should not do this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/02/10218999.aspx) The framework assumes that tasks will complete.

As @SLaks noted, if you don't, then you will cause memory leaks.